# Sum of squares in an array using recursion in golang

Tags: arrays, go, recursion

So my friend gave me this task where the sum of squares of positive numbers must be calculated using recursion. 
Conditions - The input will be a string with space separated numbers 
This is what I've come so far but this shows a `runtime error`.

Here is the full error https://ideone.com/53oOjN

```
package main
import(
    'fmt',
    'strings',
    'strconv'
)
var n int = 4
var sum_of_squares int = 0
func sumOfSquares(strArray []string, iterate int) int{
    number, _ := strconv.Atoi(strArray[iterate])
    if number > 0 {
        sum_of_squares += number*number
    }
    if iterate == n {
        return 0 // just to end the recursion
    }
    return sumOfSquares(strArray, iterate+1)
}
func main() {
    str := "1 2 3 4"
    strArray := strings.Fields(str)
    result := sumOfSquares(strArray, 0)
    fmt.Println(sum_of_squares, result)
}
```

Comment: post the error sir

Comment: It just shows runtime error. https://ideone.com/53oOjN

Comment: It also shows `index out of range` - not  just `runtime error`.

Comment: Prints the values stored in `sum_of_squares` and `result`

Comment: Please post actual code to the question and indicate the line where the code panics.   The code here has a syntax error. When syntax errors are fixed, panic points to the problem line.  From there, it should be easy to see the problem.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out why it is showing `index out of range`. Can someone help with the logic of recursion?

Comment: I've written this code. There's no actual question, just a task my friend gave me

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb in recursion is termination condition. It should exist and it should exist in the right place.

```
func sumOfSquares(strArray []string, iterate int) int{
    if iterate >= len(strArray) { 
        return sum_of_squares
    }
    number, _ := strconv.Atoi(strArray[iterate]) //TODO: handle err here
    sum_of_squares += number*number

    return sumOfSquares(strArray, iterate+1)
}
```

---

Just for you information: canonical recursion should not save it's state into global fields. I would suggest using following function signature.

```
func sumOfSquares(strArray []string, iterate, currentSum int) int{
    //...    
    return sumOfSquares(strArray, iterate+1, sum_of_squares)
}
```

So that you don't need to store `sum_of_squares` somewhere. You will just pass it to next function invocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

var n int

func sumOfSquares(strArray []string, iterate int) int {
    number, _ := strconv.Atoi(strArray[iterate])
    if iterate == n {
        return number * number
    }
    return ((number * number) + sumOfSquares(strArray, iterate+1))
}

func main() {
    str := "1 2 3 4"
    strArray := strings.Fields(str)
    n = len(strArray) - 1
    result := sumOfSquares(strArray, 0)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Indexing starts from 0, so decrease the length by one.

As @peterSO have pointed out, if strings contain unusual characters, it doesn't work, I didn't post the right answer for getting input because you seem to be beginner, but you can read the input, like this instead.

```
var inp []byte
var loc int

inp, _ = ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
//add \n so that we don't end up running out of bounds,
//if last byte is integer.
inp = append(inp, '\n')


func scanInt() (res int) {
    if loc < len(inp) {
        for ; inp[loc] < 48 || inp[loc] > 57; loc++ {
        }
        for ; inp[loc] > 47 && inp[loc] < 58; loc++ {
            res = res<<3 + res<<1 + (int(inp[loc]) - 48)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

This is faster and scans integers only, and skips all other unusual characters.

Comment: @peterSO Updated the answer, but he did mention, input is going to be string with space separated values.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep it simple. I have some few if conditions as well, but hope you like it.

```
func sumOfSquares(numArr []string) int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(numArr[0])

    rest := numArr[1:]

    //Error checking
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
        return 0
    }

    square := i * i

    // negative & last number
    if i < 0 && len(rest) == 0 {
        return square
    }

    // negative & not last number
    if i < 0 && len(rest) > 0 {
        return sumOfSquares(rest)
    }

    // last man standing
    if i >= 0 && len(rest) == 0 {
        return square
    }

    return square + sumOfSquares(rest)

}
```

DEMO : https://play.golang.org/p/WWYxKbvzanJ